# Does continuously differentiable imply the $\alpha$ order Holder condition for some $\alpha$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I am reading the book Fourier Analysis written by Stein.
The function $f$ satisfies the Holder condition of order $\alpha$ for $\alpha > 1/2$ means that $\sup_{\theta} |f(\theta + t) -f(\theta)| \leq A|t|^{\alpha}$ for all $t$.

Does "continuously differentiable" imply $f$ satisfies Holder condition for some $\alpha > 1/2$?

Comment: Locally, it implies it for $\alpha = 1$: continuously differentiable functions are Lipschitz, by the mean value theorem. Globally, on unbounded domains, it doesn't imply it for any $\alpha$ (consider $f(x) = x^2$ on $\mathbb{R}$).

Comment: @NateEldredge If I just take care of the differentiability on one point, then it makes sense, right?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by that.

Comment: You get a local Hölder condition by continuous differentiability, i.e. any point has a neighbourhood in which this is true (with $A$ depending on the neihgbourhood).